# Flutter how to modify MyApp "files" state from children?

Tags: flutter

I defined MyApp as a statefull widget, in which I also defined a list called "files" (see : **List files = [];**), but how do I access/modify this list inside of the other widgets of my app ?

I have tried this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@agungsurya/basic-state-management-in-google-flutter-6ee73608f96d) but it's between two separated pages, which is not really the case here.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'dart:developer';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List<PlatformFile> files = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    files = files ?? [];
  }

  void _removeFile(file) {
    setState(() {
      files.remove(file);
    });
  }

  void _addFile(file) {
    setState(() {
      files.add(file);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyHome(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHome extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHome({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.lightBlueAccent),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: const <Widget>[
                Text('Summarize PDF'),
                //Text('ELE2'),
                UploadFiles(),
                ShowUploadedFiles()
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class UploadFiles extends StatelessWidget {
  const UploadFiles({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () async {
        final result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(allowMultiple: true);
        if (result == null) return;
        log(result.files.toString());

        // I want to add result.files TO "files" variable (defined below class MyAppState)
      },
      child: const Text("pick file"),
    );
  }
}

class ShowUploadedFiles extends StatelessWidget {
  const ShowUploadedFiles({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Text("files ??");
    // I want to see "files" variable (defined below class MyAppState)
  }
}
```

Any idea ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You should create another class and define the file variable as a static member of that class. Then you could modify the files variable from both the classes.

Answer (score 0):

i made some change for you :

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List<PlatformFile> files = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    files = files ?? [];
  }

  void _removeFile(file) {
    setState(() {
      files.remove(file);
    });
  }

  void _addFile(file) {
    setState(() {
      files.add(file);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.lightBlueAccent),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('Summarize PDF'),
                  //Text('ELE2'),
                  UploadFiles(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      final result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(allowMultiple: true);
                      if (result == null) return;
                      log(result.files.toString());

                      // I want to add result.files TO "files" variable (defined below class MyAppState)
                    },
                  ),
                  ShowUploadedFiles()
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class UploadFiles extends StatelessWidget {
  final void Function()? onPressed;
  
  const UploadFiles({
    super.key,
    required this.onPressed
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: onPressed,
      child: const Text("pick file"),
    );
  }
}

class ShowUploadedFiles extends StatelessWidget {
  const ShowUploadedFiles({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Text("files ??");
    // I want to see "files" variable (defined below class MyAppState)
  }
}
```